# Nodal Analysis of a circuit with a dependent source

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, voltage-source

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdhF26.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hi,

So the trouble I am having with this problem is that I don't know how to do nodal analysis with the dependent source. I would normally just do a source transformation and change the current source to a voltage source and then just do KVL's. But since the dependent source is reliant on Vo, I don't know how to solve it using Nodal Analysis. Vo is the voltage across R2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voltage at the node where R2 is connected is Vo, consider voltage at other node is \$V_1\$ By KCL:

$$\frac{V_o}{R_2} + \frac{V_o-V_1}{R_1} + \frac{V_o-V_2-2V_o}{R_3} = 0$$

To find \$V_2\$ here it is simply \$R_4 \cdot I_1 = 48V\$.

Now put the values and you will get your answer.

However you can do same using the loop analysis and KVL.

The thing is keep the dependent source variable as it is and just solve as you normally do.

Comment: Use some markup on those numbers and you have my +1.

Comment: There seems to be an error here.  V2 (voltage at the top of I1) can't be 48V.  Please check.